# Liferay 6.2 modal add callback on close

Tags: javascript, liferay, yui, liferay-aui

I need to excute a generic function (console.log) on closing (on hide) modal window created with this javascript code:

```
    YUI().ready(function(A) {
        YUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window', function(A) {
            Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
                {
                    title : title,
                    uri: url,
                    dialog: {
                        cache: false,
                        modal: true
                    }
                }
            ).on('hide', function() {
                  console.log("Modal closed")});

        });
    });
```

'*url*' and '*title*' are two variables passing from code above.
It doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: is "hide" definitly the name of the event that **close** s the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work until you set **destroyOnHide** dialog option to **true**.

By default it is set to false, hence the popup will only be hidden.

See below:

```
YUI().ready(function(A) {
    YUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window', function(A) {
        Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow({
            title : title,
            uri: url,
            dialog: {
                destroyOnHide: true,
                cache: false,
                modal: true
            }
        }).after('destroy', function(event) {
                alert('DESTROY MODAL!');
        });
    });
});
```

Then you will be able to intercept **destroy** event with **after()** method as usual.

Comment: Hi, lets say we have a table and in runtime after ajax, i get data and append to popup, when it is closed i want to remove all json data in it (refresh) the template. Should i recreate ? I tried that also, but on('click') event can't catch new dom.

Answer (score 1):

Hi replace your `on('hide'` with this:

```
YUI().ready(function(A) {
    YUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window', function(A) {
        Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
            {
                title : title,
                uri: url,
                dialog: {
                    cache: false,
                    modal: true
                }
            }
      ) on: {
      close: function(event) {
              console.log("Modal closed")});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right event called on dialog close is `destroy` event.

Liferay `Window` extends `A.Component` which has `destroy` event. In fact to close a Window the right way is to call `desploy()` method.

```
AUI().ready(function(A) {
    AUI().use('aui-base','liferay-util-window', function(A) {

        Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
            {
                title : title,
                uri: url,
                dialog: {
                    cache: false,
                    modal: true
                }
            }
        ).after('destroy', function() {
              console.log("Modal closed");
        });

    });
});
```